# Set up Ingress on Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, minikube

I'm getting stuck with this problem:

[image: Every time i try to access http://hello-world.info/]

and my example-ingress.yaml is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

i've already added the route into my /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
.
.
.
192.168.49.2 hello-world.info
```

I'm on Zorin OS, minikube ip is and i'm using docker network driver:

```
$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

Comment: Please don't post images of text. Include the text itself in your question, formatted as a code sample.

Comment: Have you followed [these instructions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)?

Comment: @larsks yes, i followed enabling the Ingress controller and creating the exactly same file on my project